# Using JWT Signature to blacklist token

Tags: jwt

Is it recommended to use the signature part of the JWT token to blacklist revoked tokens? The reason is I want to fix the size of the identifier I store for the revoked token in my database. In future, I might add more data to my JWT payload, and I don't have any unique JTI in the token.

The signing algorithm I use is HS256.

Answer (score 0):

I do not really think that it is a good practice to use the signature of the JWT for any use case. Its purpose is to make the JWT unique, and "secure". After a lot of research, I found out that the best practice is to use JWT's payload. Its claims are also public, and it is much easier to work with them. For the `jti` part, you can use UUIDs. They are the best, when it comes to random and unique numbers, and especially identifiers.